# Are there any Microsoft REST APIs allowing to retrieve all Transport Rules or DLP policies from an Exchange Online?

Tags: c#, azure, outlook, office365, exchange-server

I know that there are Microsoft Graph, Azure AD Graph and simple Microsoft REST API exists but none of them have such kind of API. I know that It is possible to retrieve them using PowerShell `Get-TranportRules` cmdlet. Is it possible to get them using REST calls?

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is not possible.
According to my knowledge, all administrative actions can be done using powershell cmdlet.
I was trying to understand if it's possible to create a **session** using an **access token (Oauth authentication)** instead of user credentials in cmdlet.

Maybe you know the answer for that.